# Unfortunately, androiddemo(project name) has stopped

Tags: android

I am new with android this is my 1st demo app. I am trying to navigate from one page to another. But i am not able to navigate to another page i have a button in may main xml file and on licking it is moving to an another xml nextpage. I have 2 java class : 1st MianAcitvity, nextpagejava. 2 xml : activity_main, nextpage

My code : manifest

```
      <activity
      android:name="com.example.androiddemo.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
        <activity android:name="nextpagejava" ></activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androiddemo;
  import android.os.Bundle; 
   import android.app.Activity; 
   import android.content.Intent; 
   import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
  import android.view.Menu; 
   import android.view.View; 
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnt);
           bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                / / TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }
            }); 
            }

             @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
             return true;
            }

             @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.bnt:
                     Intent in = new Intent(this, nextpagejava.class);
                     startActivity(in);
               break;


              }
           }
          }
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
           <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

               <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/clicktxt"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Click"        
         />

           <Button
           android:id="@+id/bnt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:text="Click Me"
          />
```

nextpage.xml

```
           <TextView 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="I am i a next page..."
             />

            <Button 
              android:id="@+id/btn1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Back"
             />
```

nextpagejava.java

```
         package com.example.androiddemo;

          import android.app.Activity;
          import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.View;
          import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;

           public class nextpagejava extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            bt.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
         }
```

i am getting message that "Unfortunately, androiddemo has stopped" this message as a popup.

can anybody tell me why this error is coming and please tell me from where i can find line by line debug logs.

Comment: Can you post the error logs please...??? or you must identify yourself from the logs...

Comment: Check the stack trace using logcat and find out where the error (exception) occurred. Check out if *you* can find a solution. If not, come back and provide the actual error including stack trace!

Comment: You can find the logcat in MENU bar -> WindowBar -> ShowView-->logcat

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, what is the value of `package` in the `manifest` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this from your `MainActivity.java` file:

> ```
>   bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
>        @Override   
>        public void onClick(View v) {
>             / / TODO Auto-generated method stub
>          }
>         });
> ```

Instead of Write like this:

> ```
> bt.setOnClickListener(this);
> ```

Also do the changes in `Manifest` file as below:

> ```
> <activity android:name=".nextpagejava" ></activity>
> ```

Then check out . I think it should work now.

Answer (score 4):

```
<activity android:name="nextpagejava" ></activity>
```

needs a "."in front of activity name..

```
<activity android:name=".nextpagejava" ></activity>
```

Also change your MainActivity name to

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" ></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two onClick() functions. Remove the second one and add the following two lines inside the listener of the button

```
  Intent in = new Intent(this, nextpagejava.class);
  startActivity(in);
```

That should keep you going. If still error persists, please post your logcat

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace you get a lot of info, so put that here.

But I would say it is very likely to be related to some missing declaration (for example trying to click a button that has not been initialized); very common issue.

EDIT: probably using an Intent should fix your problem.